# How to get X-Auth-Token generate by saltstack's login module to work on multiple Master of Masters

Tags: salt-stack

I have multiple master of masters and I would like to access all of them through token which salt module generates using below command

```
curl -sSk http://localhost:8000/login \
-H 'Accept: application/x-yaml' \
-d username=\
-d password=\
-d eauth=
```

but problem is token might differ when machines are different for master of master, How can we achieve it, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

So, the ability to change the token module exists. however this is the off the beaten path and there be dragons kind of support. the documentation is pretty much non existent for this functionality. there only two token modules built in. localfs and rediscluster. so if you want something else you are going to have to make it yourself.

the default token module is the localfs module. which will store the tokens in the local fileserver for the master. which as you can guess does not cover the situation your are talking about. you need a backend system that both masters can communicate with and a token module that will talk to that backend.

the master config to set what the tokens are stores in is eauth_tokens.

here is about all the documentation that exists.

- https://docs.saltproject.io/en/master/topics/development/modules/index.html#tokens
- https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/tokens/all/index.html
- https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/tokens/all/salt.tokens.rediscluster.html#module-salt.tokens.rediscluster
- https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/master/salt/tokens/__init__.py

Comment: thanks @whytewolf , your inputs seems to be giving me some direction... Using Redis Cluster to store token and then writing custom module to validate the token seems like a plausible approach, what are your thoughts on the same?

Comment: Those two things would be mutually exclusive. tokens are authenticated by the call to get_token which happens in the token module. so your module would have to handle the storing and authentication of the token. now you could use the rediscluster as a basis for your token and change the mk_token and get_token functions to better suite your needs.